# Pandas groupby ffill zero values at end of the series

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace all the last zeros of a grouped series by the last non-zero value. So hence this code :

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0], 'b': [12,0 ,14, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
a.index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
a = a.unstack() 
a = a.reset_index().set_index('level_1') 
a.columns = ['item', 'value'] 
a.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

I'd like to arrive to this result

```
    item    value
level_1     
1   a   1
1   b   12
2   a   2
2   b   0
3   a   0
3   b   14
4   a   3
4   b   14
5   a   5
5   b   14
6   a   5'
6   b   14
7   a   5
7   b   14
```

Notice how the zeros between 2 and 3, and between 12 and 14 remained, but the ending zeros all were forward filled.

See below how I managed to get the indexes of the last non-zero values cleanly, but can't get the rest done.

```
a.groupby('item').apply(lambda x : [x != 0].index[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible use original DataFrame replace `0` to missing values by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and then in another `mask` forward filling only last missing values by `ffill`, what is tested by back filling with check `NaN`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0], 'b': [12,0 ,14, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
df.index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
print (df)
   a   b
1  1  12
2  2   0
3  0  14
4  3   0
5  5   0
6  0   0
7  0   0

df1 = df.mask(df.eq(0))
df =  df.mask(df1.bfill().isna(), df1.ffill())
print (df)
   a   b
1  1  12
2  2   0
3  0  14
4  3  14
5  5  14
6  5  14
7  5  14
```

If not, first reshape to original, apply solution aand then reshape back:

```
df = a.set_index('item', append=True).unstack()
df1 = df.mask(df.eq(0))
df = df.mask(df1.bfill().isna(), df1.ffill()).stack().reset_index(level=1)
print (df)
        item  value
level_1            
1          a      1
1          b     12
2          a      2
2          b      0
3          a      0
3          b     14
4          a      3
4          b     14
5          a      5
5          b     14
6          a      5
6          b     14
7          a      5
7          b     14
```

Per groups similar idea:

```
def f(x):
    m = x['value'].eq(0)
    s = x['value'].mask(m)
    x['value'] = s.fillna(0).mask(s.bfill().isna(), s.ffill())
    return x

df = a.reset_index().groupby('item').apply(f)
print (df)
    level_1 item  value
0         1    a    1.0
1         1    b   12.0
2         2    a    2.0
3         2    b    0.0
4         3    a    0.0
5         3    b   14.0
6         4    a    3.0
7         4    b   14.0
8         5    a    5.0
9         5    b   14.0
10        6    a    5.0
11        6    b   14.0
12        7    a    5.0
13        7    b   14.0
```